# How to save user profile photo getting from graph api to file by using powershell

Tags: powershell, api, graph

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<UPN>/photo/$value"

$photoresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers -ContentType = image/jpeg
$photoresponse
```

The API response seems to be fine as below:

```
@odata.context           : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#user('<UPN>')/photo/$entity
@odata.mediaContentType  : image/jpeg
@odata.mediaEtag         : "210DFD48"
id                       : 120*120
height                   : 120
width                    : 120
```

I did not manage to save it to a jpeg local file. It looks like I need to do some encoding to convert (base64?), but I am still confused about that.

All I would like to do is make this photo to be downloaded to a local file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was just running into this issue myself and I found that you need to use the -OutFile parameter of the Invoke-RestMethod.  I was searching all over trying to identify how to "Convert" this as it describes in Microsoft's documentation "When you use the /photo/$value endpoint to get the binary data for a profile photo, you'll need to convert the data into a base-64 string"

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UPN/photo/$value"

$photoresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers -ContentType image/jpeg **-OutFile** C:\SomePath

$photoresponse
```